# How to get photos where user is tagged from facebook API in android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get users photos(tagged and uploaded) using facebook api?

I am using the following code but it is giving output as `{"data":[]}`.

```
URL img_url = null;
try {
    img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/10152463935954109/photos");
}catch (MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
try {
    InputStream in = img_value.openConnection().getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```